# Why is my XTR M9100 crank fouling the chainstay?

Tags: press-fit, xtr

I have two identical frames, other than age. A 2016 Production Privee Shan 27 and a 2019 Production Privee Shan 27.

The 2016 Shan 27 was running full XTR, with an M9100 crankset. This is 162mm QF, 175mm crank and compatible with 142/148 O.L.D.

The bottom bracket is a wheels manufacturing BB92 pressfit.

This bike was built by me and worked flawlessly.

I moved the BB and XTR crankset to the newer Shaan 27, and the crank fouls the driveside chainstay. Not by a margin, but by a lot.

Both bikes measure:
92mm BB
142mm rear dropouts
41mm BB dia.

The clearance between 2016 Shan 27 and inside edge of DS crank is a good 3 or 4mm. On the 2019 bike, there's no clearance, the DS crank is unable to complete a rotation.

Both frames align in a jig perfectly.

[image]

[image]

More images at:    https://photos.app.goo.gl/cvHSJVe9eiSkAWkx9

Update. Measurements of the BB in relation to seat post are identical, sadly. However, the effective BB width on the 2019 Shan is 2mm wider (with the bb installed). However it's the 2019 bike that has the issue. Does a wider effective BB reduce overall crank spindle length which then causes some strange behavior on the drive side?

Comment: Are you sure the two frames have the exactly same size? If I recollect correctly there were quite some change from the 2015 models to the 2019. Something like the axle going from 142 mm to Boost (148 mm).
I guess you can fit your old wheelset in the 2019 model, 6mm are not that much difference ... and then you get a nasty surprise ;)

Comment: Can you say what happens when you swap the parts between the frames… starting with whatever part means most to you?

Comment: No, both frames are 142mm rear drop out non boost.

Comment: I can swap the same bottom bracket between frames, no spacers required. I then install the m9100 crank in the 2016 frame and it has 3-5mm of clearance on the drive side crank. I can swap them back to 2019 frame and there's zero clearance.

Comment: Does the nds arm clear?

Comment: Yes. On both frames. But geater on 2016 frame by 1mm or so

Comment: Are you sure the BB and BB Shell are both straight?  If all other measurements are approximately equal, that would be all I can think of.

Comment: On your last image, it sure looks like the BB shell on the white frame could be offset to the non-drive side.  I'd carefully measure that on both frames - say BB shell edge to seat tube, down tube, and chainstays on both sides of both frames, and also measure the distance between the chainring's teeth and the seat tube when the *same* crankset is installed on both frames.

Comment: @EarlGrey the 2019 model should still be 142mm (and the photos show 142mm).
https://www.vitalmtb.com/product/guide/Frames,7/Production-Privee/Shan,20525
Andrews comment above is correct, the drive side chainstay seems to be much closer to the edge of the bottom bracket than on the older bike.  That could be a manufacturing fault, or it could be a subtle design change to accommodate a wider tyre.

Comment: @Lucero79 thanks for updating with pictures.  I'm not sure they show my answer is wrong yet, but if it does prove to be wrong i'll be happy to delete it.

Comment: @Lucero79 is it possible a shim/spacer was left inside the old frame's BB ?

Comment: Using Occam's razor, the most likely explanation is that the frames are a little more different than you think. I'm trusting you did the BB install correctly. Have you contacted the manufacturer asking for more info?

Comment: @AndrewHenle agree, see cropped image https://ibb.co/wgSqdf9

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I have reach out to Production Privee who say there is no difference in technical design / drawings that they can reference and in fact the crank should fit both bikes the same. I am going to take more measurements this weekend, specifically total effective BB width (ie, with the BB installed) and also BB shell face to seat post/seat post centre.

Comment: Could it be that the BB shell is not perfectly perpendicular to the frames centerline? I would use a straightedge, sliding it touching the drive side edges of the shell and see where it intersect with the chainstay (I think this point will be very different for both frames.), or if said ruler, seen from directly above, follows the same line as the down tube.

Comment: Update. Measurements of the BB in relation to seat post are identical, sadly. However, the effective BB width on the 2019 Shan is 2mm wider (with the bb installed). However it's the 2019 bike that has the issue. Does a wider effective BB reduce overall crank spindle length which then causes some strange behavior on the drive side?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. I'm still curious if there's a difference in distance between the BB face and the chainstay attachment point between the two frames,did you get a chance to measure that as well?

Comment: @Lucero79 Did you measure if the *blue* frame has a symmtric bottom bracket shell?  Looking at the picture embedded into your question, there sure looks to be more space between the crankset and the right chainstay than there is betwwn the left chainstay and the left edge of the bottom bracket shell.

Answer (score 5):

By comparing the two images from your [google photos album](https://photos.app.goo.gl/cvHSJVe9eiSkAWkx9) where you measure the outside chainstay width, it seems very likely (to me) that the bottom bracket has a different offset in the white frame compared to the blue frame.

Admittedly, the photo perspectives are not exactly the same, but if you overlay the two images in e.g. Gimp, toggle the layer and change the opacity, the difference seems visible:

[image: Images of two different bottom brackets overlaid and alternatively shown in a GIF]

Of course, this is best confirmed by an actual measurement (as already suggested in [the comments](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/87367/why-is-my-xtr-m9100-crank-fouling-the-chainstay#comment206393_87367) by [Andrew Henle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/21107/andrew-henle)).

Comment: maybe we are all tricked by the black marks on the older frame :) . Let's see the hard numbers.

Comment: @EarlGrey I've updated the original post

Answer (score 4):

Given all the details and measurments, I think the only way to explain this is a small angle in the bb housing (either the shell, or the bb itself), but if you follow the calculations you will see I am not convinced by my own hypothesis.

From a small angle of $theta$ in the bottom bracket position there will be a deviation inward (or outward) of sin($theta$) times the length of the pedal crank.

To get a bend of 6-7 mmm (since in 2016 frame you had a gap of 3-4 mm, and now the crank hits the chainstay) you would need a bend of around 4-5 degrees. I think it is a lot (on your watch, it would be the angle corresponding to one minute) and I would exclude this, but I don't know what are the tolerances (if you are curious about this topic, check the deep rabbit hole of [hambini and his technical rants/rambilings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWDztuezn0g) on youtube ...).

Comment: Bending the crank arm will make the pedal bore out of true - you'd feel it on every pedal stroke.

Comment: @Criggie I agree on the crank arm, I was thinking more in terms of "everything is slightly bent" because the bb axis is not straight. I agree that you would probably feel it on every stroke ... but then, OP cannot pedal the 2019 bicycle!

Comment: If only bicycles SE actually supported LaTeX...

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing anything about this specific company, it's plausible that what they supply their frame producer with is either a drawing that describes minimum clearances at various points relative to the BB shell faces, and/or a go/no-go gauge that plugs into the shell bore to quickly QC test for clearances on the completed frame or rear end assembly. If so it's possible to imagine a situation where these clearance specs and the tooling used to check them didn't change between the two production years, but something about the process or materials did change, such that a crank that actually exceeded the clearance specs on the earlier generation but worked anyway didn't work anymore. If they're being honest that nothing in the design changed, and if the rear end does in fact not have any alignment problems, this is what's likely going on here.

You mention having a jig to measure or test the alignment, but note that not all frame jigs reference the BB surfaces in the same way. To rule out alignment you'd need to test rear end alignment relative to the center plane between the shell faces specifically. Some ways of measuring (such as a Park Frame Alignment Gauge in the simplest example) could make the rear end look aligned but are perfectly capable of not detecting an error in the centering of the shell.

When chainstays are dimpled at the factory, as seen on many steel frames, it's done cold with blunt force. You could attempt to do that here. The simple thing would be making a wood form to cradle the backside of the chainstay with lots of surface area contact, and then press a solid steel form into right where you need the clearance. Generally this approach is safe and is how many framebuilders dimple chainstays. In your case, you'd be doing it right on the sharp side of where the biaxial chainstay has already been ovalized. It would still probably be fine, although it's true there's some increased risk of things going wrong because it's already been manipulated in that area pretty extensively.